# SilverStripe Admin Login Refreshes but does not redirect

Tags: php, .htaccess, authentication, admin, silverstripe

I am slightly new to SilverStripe and the issue I have bumped into is that when going to /admin, the login page appears fine however, when adding the credentials and clicking the login button, it just refreshes and does not go to the admin page.

I did the same configurations locally and it redirects to the admin page just fine.

I also bumped into a similar issue on their community page and they mentioned it was a htaccess configuration however, I tried their suggestions but did not work.

Does anyone have a similar issue or better yet, if they had the same issue and overcame it somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Having followed the tutorials in the silverstripe docs, the first few tutorials we removed content from the file 'Page.ss', that file originally had the $Form variable in it.

Fix:

Put the $Form variable back into that page 'Page.ss' located under templates/Layout

For e.g.

```
 <section>
  <div class="container">
    $Form
  </div>
 </section>
```